# How to get an alert with the values of all text fields?

Tags: javascript, html, submit

I've got a normal button and a submit button. The button is adding an extra row with a text field to the table and this works. When I click the submit button I want it to show the values of all available text fields in an alert. Now I know this has to be done in a `for` loop and I was thinking about something like this:

```
for(i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++) {
  ...
}
```

I also tried to just make the submit button come up with an alert but that's not even working.

How do I get the submit button to show me the values of the text fields?

See this as example:
http://jsfiddle.net/68N7x/7/

Comment: I suppose that your need is for testing only, in this case you should use a tool like Firebug: it allows you to inspect/modify everything in a web page and also to inspect requests and responses.

Comment: @Pino I do want it for testing but also maybe even use it in a different variant in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str="";
for(i=0; i<table.rows.length()-1; i++)
{
    str+=table[i].Text;
}
return str;
```